# Can I credit travel on one RailTeam member to the frequent traveller program of another?

Tags: europe, loyalty-programs, high-speed-rail

I know that with airline alliances and partnerships, you can credit flights on one airline in the alliance/partnership to a frequent traveller program of another. Does the same thing apply for travel with [RailTeam](http://www.railteam.co.uk/), which is the partnership of several European high speed rail operators?

I know that if you have suitable status on one RailTeam member (Eurostar, SNCF/TGV, DB or Thalys) that you can get [lounge access](http://www.railteam.co.uk/for-your-journey/railteam-services/lounges/) when travelling on another in the partnership, so at least some airline-like things apply. What I'm not sure is if I can travel on one RailTeam member, and credit the points to the program of another? Their [frequent traveller page](http://www.railteam.co.uk/for-your-journey/railteam-services/frequent-travellers/) doesn't seem to say.

(In case it matters, I'm a member of the Eurostar program, and I'm wondering about credit for some TGV journeys I've got coming up)

Answer (score 1):

You can credit most TGV travels (to/from England, Belgium, Luxembourg, Germany, Switzerland) on the SNCF Voyageur traveler program, that's for sure, I read it in the [conditions](https://www.programme-voyageur.sncf.com/non-logue/conditions-generales?init=true#conditions-generales-programme-voyageur), each euro being worth 4 SNCF Voyageur points, plus one status point. It applies only if either departure or arrival is in France, though.

But I don't think there is any compatibility with other Railteam members (no occurence of the word Railteam in the conditions)