# How does the SNCF Voyageur program work?

Tags: trains, france, loyalty-programs, high-speed-rail, sncf

I'm planning some TGV trips soon, but despite being a member of two different Railteam frequent traveller programs already, [from this question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/9662/can-i-credit-travel-on-one-railteam-member-to-the-frequent-traveller-program-of) it doesn't look like I'd be able to credit the journeys on a TGV to either of them.

I think, if I want to get any credit for them, I'll need to join the [SNCF Voyageur Program](http://www.sncf.com/en/loyalty/voyageur-programme). The [English language website for it](http://www.sncf.com/en/loyalty/voyageur-programme) has some broad details about the program, but doesn't really explain much about how you earn credit from TGV journeys, nor about redeeming them. It links through to various French language websites, but these all seem to have even less information on them, with all the important details apparently only available after you log in. (Since joining seems to take about a week, you can't just sign up and immediately see the details, grr....)

If someone with better google-fu than me, or someone who's a member who can log in to the site to get the full details, is able to post about the program that would be great. Specifically, I'm interested in:

- What tickets I can and can't get credit for
- What's the earnings rate (per segment, per mile, per euro, something else?)
- How do the different levels work?
- How do the rewards work?

Hopefully from that, I can work out if there's actually any point in me joining the program for just a few trips or not!

Comment: I don't have a full answer, but the program's first reward is at 10 trips a year (with a not-so-wonderful 10% coupon valid on a future travel), and then at 20 trips per year (where you gain access to the *Grand Voyageur* status, which starts to have some real advantages). One nice advantage is electronic ticketing, which means your tickets are (in TGV trains) associated with your card and you never have to worry about them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What tickets I can and can't get credit for

Benefits accrue for SNCF journeys in France (not including TER, Transilien, iDTGV and Ouigo) priced at more than €9 or the Forfait fare, and for selected international journeys. ([Source](http://www.sncf.com/en/loyalty/voyageur-programme))

> What's the earnings rate (per segment, per mile, per euro, something else?)

Per journey, e.g. you get discounts after ten journeys, with return tickets counting as two journeys, and you become a Grand Voyageur after 20 journeys in less than a year (or accumulate 800 Status Points).  You get "Status Points" that accumulate per Euro spent.

> How do the different levels work?
>   How do the rewards work?

They're split per level.

For the base [Voyageur](http://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=fr&u=http://aide.voyages-sncf.com/tout-sur-votre-programme-de-fidelite/votre-programme-de-fidelite-voyageur/tout-sur-votre-programme-de-fidelite-voyageur/voyageur-les-avantages-du-programme-de-fidelite-voyageur&prev=/search?q=sncf%2bvoyageur&rls=com.microsoft%3aen-au%3aIE-Address):

> - A reduction of 10% in the path of your choice as soon as you have
>     reached the threshold of 10 trips (offer subject to conditions), and
>     20% after 20 trips (offer subject to conditions). This offer is
>     combinable with the tariff advantages your subscriptions and discount
>     cards SNCF (applicable offer after reducing your discount card or
>     subscription SNCF).
> - You will also receive special offers on your
>     favorite route to share with your loved destinations.

For [Grand Voyageur](http://translate.google.com.au/translate?hl=en&sl=fr&u=http://aide.voyages-sncf.com/tout-sur-votre-programme-de-fidelite/votre-programme-de-fidelite-grand-voyageur/tout-sur-votre-programme-de-fidelite-grand-voyag/grand-voyageur-les-avantages-du-programme-de-fidelite-grand-voyageur&prev=/search?q=Grand%2bVoyageur&hl=en):

> - You can earn points based off your travel.
> - Your accumulated points can be redeemed against train tickets or gifts (subject to
>     conditions bids)
> - Discounts on luggage service
> - Access to Tellers
>     and Grand Voyager Pro in the main stations of France
> - A dedicated by
>     calling 0892330330 every weekday from 8h to 20h telephone line
> - Personalized offers sent by e-mail throughout the year (subject to
>     conditions)
> - The e-ticket services in the loyalty card

For [Grand Voyageur Plus](http://translate.google.com.au/translate?hl=en&sl=fr&u=http://aide.voyages-sncf.com/tout-sur-votre-programme-de-fidelite/votre-programme-de-fidelite-grand-voyageur-plus/tout-sur-votre-programme-de-fidelite-grand-/grand-voyageur-plus-les-avantages-du-programme-de-fidelite-grand-voyageur-plus&prev=/search?q=Grand%2bVoyageur%2bPlus&hl=en):

As above, plus

> - Access to rooms Grand Voyageur SNCF (reception point and exchange tickets, Internet connection via Wifi, Fax, Copier, offices and comfortable seating ...)

For [Grand Voyageur le Club](http://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=fr&u=http://aide.voyages-sncf.com/tout-sur-votre-programme-de-fidelite/votre-programme-de-fidelite-grand-voyageur-le-club/tout-sur-votre-programme-de-fidelite-gra/grand-voyageur-le-club-les-avantages-du-programme-de-fidelite-grand-voyageur-le-club&prev=/search?q=Grand%2bVoyageur%2bLe%2bClub&rls=com.microsoft%3aen-au%3aIE-Address):

As above, plus:

> - The access to the next train * allows greater flexibility in your schedule. Less stress if a meeting or an appointment continues: you take the next train without having to exchange your ticket.
> - The Exchange trainload * allows you to exchange your original ticket to leave earlier than expected, on the same route and the same day. The train is full? No problem, you can access it anyway! * This service is valid regardless of the ticket price, excluding non-exchangeable, non-refundable.